# Append element on multiple if conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Paul Johnson</td>
    <th>Birthdate</th>
    <td>28th May 1974</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Street</th>
    <td>Fake Street 148</td>
    <th>City</th>
    <td>New York</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There is a script that is executed by mouseenter event

```
$('th').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {

});
```

inside it is code below

```
var toolbar = $("<div />").css({
      "padding": "5px",
      "background" : "#F8F8F8" 
      "borderRadius" : "5px 0 5px 5px",
      "left" : "-30px",
      "top" : "0",
      "zIndex" : "99"
    });

toolbar.append( gmaps ).append( google ).append( phone ).append( copy );

$(this).append( toolbar );
```

and link inside toolbar

```
    var link = $("<a />").css({
      "display" : "block",
      "height" : "20px",
      "width" : "20px",
      "marginBottom" : "5px",
      "background-size" : "100%",
      "position" : "relative"})
      .attr({"target" : "_blank"
});
```

There are many kinds of links, more than 100 variants. There is for example two of them

```
var thisNext = $( $(this).parent().next('td') ).text();

    var gmaps = link.clone().css({
      "background" : "url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pwcubxu7xoigavz/maps.png) no-repeat",
      "background-size": "100%",
    }).attr({href: 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/' + thisNext });

    var google = link.clone().css({
      "background" : "url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ja0plpnomx3v0jn/find.png) no-repeat",
      "background-size": "100%",
    }).attr({href: 'https://www.google.cz/search?q=' + thisNext });
```

I have got more tables on site, but table like this shouldnt append nothing

```
<table>
  <th>User</th>
  <td>John</td>
</table>
```

My questions/goals:

- variable thisNext should get data from next td element ( if user
  clicks to name, it should get Paul Johnson etc ), but my code do not
  works
- not each th should append toolbar, for exemple City should do nothing - vhat is the best solution to define which elements should append toolbar?
- if is user "John" th element street should append gmaps and
  google inside toolbar, if is user "Steve" same element should append only google. For another th element should "Steve" get both links, "John" nothing etc.

here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWZZjd?editors=1010)

I cant make it with classes, ids etc. I need to make only with raw table just like I posted.

Comment: Why can't you use classes and ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate solution using hashmap of options based on known names as keys and indexing of dom elements:

```
var config = {
  "John" : {"map": "gmap", "links":[1,4,6]},
  "Steve" : {"map": "bing", "links":'all'}
}
```

Assume table is first table in page and toolbar goes in 2nd cell on row where name is also located

```
var $table = $('table').eq(0);
$table.find('tr>th:eq(1)').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
        var opts = config[$(this).text()];
        if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
```

This will certainly take some fine tuning but using indexing is likely your best approach

Answer (score 0):

- ### 1

  > variable thisNext should get data from next td element ( if user clicks to name, it should get Paul Johnson etc ), but my code do not works

`$(this)` refers to `<th>` element, so desired `<td>` is just its next sibling:

```
var thisNext = $(this).next().text();
```

---

- ### 2

  > not each th should append toolbar, for exemple City should do nothing - vhat is the best solution to define which elements should append toolbar?

You can get `<th>`'s content to determine its "type" and then decide based on it:

```
var this_type = $(this).text();
//"User", "Street", "City", etc.

if (this_type === 'City'){
    //append nothing
} else if (this_type === 'Street'){
    toolbar.append( gmaps ).append( google ); //for example
} else {
    // default (for all the rest "types")

    toolbar.append( gmaps ).append( google ).append( phone ).append( copy );
}
```

---

- ### 3

  > if is user "John" th element street should append gmaps and google inside toolbar, if is user "Steve" same element should append only google. For another th element should "Steve" get both links, "John" nothing etc.

So we have different set of buttons for different users.
Do you have separate page for each user, or are they all on the same page?

First, let's get the current user (for one user — one page case):

```
/**
 * Finds username on the page.
 * If a table on the page has only one <td>, it's considered a table with username
 */
function determineCurrentUser (){
    $('table').each(function(){
        var $td_elements = $(this).find('td');
        if ( $td_elements.length === 1 ){
            return $td_elements.eq(0).text();
        }
    });
    return false;
}

//How to use:
//Somewhere not in a loop (to call it only once)
var user = determineCurrentUser();
```

Second, deside what buttons to append based on user:

```
if (user === 'John'){
    if (this_type === 'City'){
        //append nothing
    } else if (this_type === 'Street'){
        toolbar.append( gmaps ).append( google );
    } else {
        // default (for all the rest "types")
        toolbar.append( gmaps ).append( google ).append( phone ).append( copy );
    }
} else if (user === 'Steve'){
    if (this_type === 'City'){
        //append nothing
    } else if (this_type === 'Street'){
        //only `google` for Steve's street
        toolbar.append( google );
    } else {
        // default (for all the rest "types")
        toolbar.append( gmaps ).append( google ).append( phone ).append( copy );
    }
}
```

*
I would also put all per-user and per-th-type rules to a config object somewhere not in the mouseenter handler, but that's next step.

Comment: using `if` for user is not very scalable for large number of users

Comment: @charlietfl I absolutely agree.
I would put all per-user and per-th-type rules to a config object somewhere not in the mouseenter handler, but that's next step.
And that's not the only optimization i would suggest for that code;)...

Comment: @karolina-ticha Does this answer help? Maybe you have any questions?

Answer (score -1):

For starters use class to denote elements that should have toolbar.

You could pass a config object to `data-` attribute for the various options if this is being rendered server side. If it is being rendered client side use `data()` method to store on element

```
 <tr data-toolbar-options='{"map": "gmap", "links":[1,4,6]}'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td class="has-toolbar" >Paul Johnson</td>
    <th>Birthdate</th>
    <td>28th May 1974</td>
  </tr>
```

JS

```
$('th.has-toolbar').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
        var opts = $(this).parent().data('toolbar-options');
        if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
          // use opts to determine what goes in toolbar
```

Use indexing to figure out `next/previous`

Comment: You are using clasess, but in my project I cant.

Comment: Why not? You have to be able to distinguish somehow which gets toolbar and which doesn't. You are asking for a lot without defining limitations criteria. Is this html generated server side or client side from json?

Comment: Because I just cant. I have no access to html code, Im creating only custom javascript code hooked over browser extension.

Comment: Then you need to isolate those tables by index...or by their parent or something. As for which `<th>` you would need some other way to determine which gets toolbar and which not. Perhaps also by index. As for Steve vs John that would have to be mapped out somehow manually